# Symfony Handle exception thrown from service, which got called from other service

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony Application an Controller calls `ServiceA`, which then calls `ServiceB`.

I want to catch exception from `ServiceB` in my Controller, how can I do that?

Do I need to catch it in `ServiceA`, then rethrow it to Controller? Is there a better way?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Catch it in the controller services should be independent from each other unless you have lets say transaction that needs to be rolled back from serviceA..